# Spring JdbcTemplate "insert into.. select from.." not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am trying to execute following SQL with Spring JdbcTemplate:

```
INSERT INTO japan_wht.PIVOT_20427002(doc_header_text, value_date, total_amt, is_refund)                    
 (SELECT 
    doc_header_text, DATE(value_date), SUM(LOCAL_CCY_AMT), is_refund
 FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        japan_wht.DATA_20427002
    WHERE IS_REFUND in ('N')
    ) t 
GROUP BY DATE(value_date) , doc_header_text, is_refund)
```

However, it does not insert anything into database table and no error is thrown.

When I tried to execute following SQL with JdbcTemplate, it works and inserts data in DB table:

```
INSERT INTO japan_wht.PIVOT_20427002(id, doc_header_text, value_date, total_amt, is_refund) values('1', '1', '2017-12-31', 3000, 'Y');
```

Below is my call to execute above SQLs:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(sqlString);
```

Not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: can show us the `sqlString` please?

Comment: What kind of exception do you get? Can you run this `SELECT INTO` manually?

Comment: @YCF_L: sqlString is the SQLs I have given in question...

Comment: @Tamas Rev: I am not getting any exception. Just data is not getting inserted. Select statement when run manually on its own does return data...

Comment: Run the select statement in a DB client program (SqlSquirrel, DB Visualizer etc) and see if it returns any rows.

Comment: So, what happens when you run this SQL manually? Maybe that doesn't return data either. In that case, your template works perfectly.

Comment: @dsp_user: :) yes off course I have done that! Please read comment reply I have given to Tamas Rev on top of your comment!

Comment: @Tamas Rev: I mentioned to you in my comment above - "Select statement when run manually on its own does return data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to resort to plain JDBC and it worked:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mySchema?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true",
    "root", "root");
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
int flag = stmt.executeUpdate(sqlString);
LOGGER.info("Flag = {}", flag);
```

Not sure why Spring JdbcTemplate can not handle such thing!

Comment: do u have the answer why the jdbc template dint work.. what was the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `execute` method. Like:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO table1 (some_id, some_key, some_text) " +
      "SELECT id, key, text from table2 t2 " +
      "LIMIT ?", (PreparedStatementCallback<Boolean>) ps -> {
                      ps.setInt(1, 400);
                      return ps.execute();
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run it in IDEA, check temporally files if you open DB from resource file.
I store my DB file exampleDB.db in src/main/resorces/db folder, so i found my temporally db file in build/resources/main/db/exampleDB.db. Try to open it temporally file to check it contain.