# How to get millions of data from table and insert another table with spring-jdbc

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

I have to read 2 millions of record from oracle db with spring jdbc and insert all records to another table.First of all, I tried to get all data with parallel select statement by using spring jdbcTemplate but rowMapper process does not finish.Then I wanted to use `insert into tableA select * from tableB` also this process does not finish.Do you have any idea how I can solve this situation with spring jdbc.

I found some batchUpdate examples but all of them contains a list of data but I cannot have a list because select query does not finish.

Is there any example?

Comment: You should take a look at Spring Batch for those kind of operation. You will have to ude data chunk to split your records : https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch

Comment: Unless you need to do some processing in your middle-tier (Spring) then this should all be done on the database using `INSERT INTO tablea SELECT * FROM tableb;` and should never return anything (other than maybe the number of rows affected) to the middle-tier. Taking data backwards and forwards between the two is just a waste of effort and time.

Comment: @MT0 How can i do with spring batch?All batch examples on the web contains a ready list data but in my case there is no list I have to get it from db.I mean the fastest way to add INSERT INTO tablea SELECT * FROM tableb statement.Am i right?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46194762/1509264

Answer (score 0):

I would break the query by pagination so you can get chunks, and then you can buffer it so that your JVM does not crash due to lack of memory; additionally, get a read-committed transaction lock on it, so there are no anomalies once the data is retrieved. I am sorry I do not have code to share with you about this, but I hope the general idea helped.

Here is an example query that can help.

```sql
select * from TABLENAME LIMIT 20 OFFSET 100
```

Comment: Oracle does not support the `LIMIT ... OFFSET ...` syntax. Depending on version, you need to either use `ROWNUM` or `OFFSET ... ROWS FETCH NEXT ... ROWS`.